# C#: How to refer to default(T) and constructors in xml comments

Tags: c#, generics, xml-documentation

I have this class you see below in the answer. There I can refer to for example the `Value` with `<see cref="Value"/>`, and the class itself with `<see cref="GenericEventArgs{T}"/>`.

1. How can I refer to default(T)? Is it even possible?
2. How can I refer to the constructors?

---

```
/// <summary>
/// A simple <see cref="EventArgs"/> class that can contain a value.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of <see cref="Value"/>.</typeparam>
public class GenericEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiates a <see cref="GenericEventArgs{T}"/> with 
    /// <see cref="default"/> default as Value.
    /// </summary>
    public GenericEventArgs()
        : this(default(T)) {}


    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiates a <see cref="GenericEventArgs{T}"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public GenericEventArgs(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The value.
    /// </summary>
    public T Value { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: ?  Is this sample code?  Because the compiler should do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .net documentation itself referes to this as: "the default value for the type of the value parameter".

See the Documentation of [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No, I think it is not possible. Since the class is JITed at runtime with the correct types, the documentation is independent of the actual types used. If you use a class constraint, you can substitute default with "null".